# Getting Music from my Ubuntu One account into Ubuntu One Music?

Tags: music, ubuntu-one

I get the message: credentials not satisfied in Ubuntu Music. How can I get the downloaded music from Ubuntu One into my Ubuntu music player. I am using a Samsung Galaxy S2/ Ypur help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a bug : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-android-music/+bug/684461

A fix was released according to the bug report.

does updating the system fix your problem ?

If not, I would advise you file a bug report on this.

Comment: I don't think apt works well on Android. :) Updating from the Market should work though.